# How to insert text from RTF to Word Document in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, rtf

I am using winservice for creating Word docs.
The only problem I have is to Paste rtf to word Selection.

I have this code:

```
private static void PasteRtf(object bookmarkName, 
                             OFFICE.Application wordApplication, 
                             Document wordDocument, string rtfText, bool winservice)
    {
        if(bookmarkName == null ||
           wordApplication == null ||
           wordDocument == null) return;

        if (!winservice)
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();
            Clipboard.SetText(rtfText, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
            IDataObject formatedText = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            if (formatedText != null)
            {
                wordDocument.Bookmarks[bookmarkName].Range.Select();
                Selection sel = wordApplication.Selection;
                sel.Paste();
            }
            Clipboard.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            ????

        }
    }
```

Do you have any idea how to do that without using Clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your RTF text (or Word, or any other compatible format) is located in a file, you may use Range.InsertFile or Bookmark.InsertFile method:

```
string FileName = "C:\\Sales.docx";
object ConfirmConversions = false;
object Link = false;
object Attachment = false;
bookmark1.InsertFile(FileName, ref missing, ref ConfirmConversions, ref Link, ref Attachment);
```

[Range.InsertFile Method (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835231.aspx)
[Bookmark.InsertFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.bookmark.insertfile.aspx)

Comment: No, I have rtf in string. I have it saved in the database in NCLOB column. Then I need to insert in into the doc ...

Comment: So, finally it seems to work fine. I did this:
- use winforms' RichTextBox (tb) control, and set rtfstring to it's property tb.Rtf.
-  save rtf file: tb.SaveFile(fileName, wf.RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText); ... file's extension = .rtf
- use by your advice selection.InsertFile

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

```
wordDocument.Bookmarks[bookmarkName].Range.Select();
Selection sel = wordApplication.Selection;

wf.RichTextBox tb = new wf.RichTextBox();
tb.Rtf = rtfText;

string fileName = Path.Combine(UserInfo.User.TempPath,
                                                   Guid.NewGuid() + ".rtf");

tb.SaveFile(fileName, wf.RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);

object ConfirmConversions = false;
object Link = false;
object Attachment = false;
object lMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
sel.InsertFile(fileName, ref lMissing, ref ConfirmConversions, ref Link, ref Attachment);

File.Delete(fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Word requires a converter in order to integrate RTF into a document. Converters run only when

1. Content is pasted from the Clipboard (which you say you don't want)
2. A file is opened or inserted (which SashaDu suggested and you also don't want)

There is no option for "streaming" RTF (or HTML, for that matter) into a Word document.

The only other possibility is for you to first convert the RTF to valid WordOpenXML in the OOPC flat-file format. That can be inserted into the document using Word's Range.InsertXml method. There are probably third-party tools out there that could do this for you. Or you'd need to write your own RTF->WordOpenXML converter.